# Determine if aspx page was opened by a window.open() command

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

Is there a way to determine in the child page's code behind that is was opened by the window.open() javascript command from the parent page?

The pop-up page contains a user control that is used by other pages that are not spawned from a window.open() command and I want to dynamically add functionality to close the page after the user has completed their task in the child page.

It is an ASP.NET C# 3.5 application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you pass through a flag in the querystring which will indicate where the window was spawned from?

Comment: I created a property on the user conrtrol to indicate if it contained with a page that is spawned by a pop up window

Answer (score 3):

in javascript you can check if window.opener is null

Answer (score 1):

The request for the child window will probably have an HTTP `Referer` (referrer) header that points to the parent page. You could check that at the backend or check `window.opener` on client side.

Comment: I tried this solution and it threw a NullReferenceException when I tried to get the Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath

Answer (score 0):

Might be wrong, but I don't think there's a simple direct way to do this.  You could always try to identify it from a distinct url, e.g. "MyChildForm.aspx?from=winopen"

--Edit-- Beaten to it by Galwegian

Answer (score 0):

You could add some javascript in the usercontrol to test whether window.opener is non-null and on that basis hide or show the close page UI.